Explicit formula for a sequence that repeats the pattern $\overbrace{0,0,..,0,0}^{k} \space 1$ for a given $k$
I want to construct a sequence that goes like this $\overbrace{0,0,..,0,0}^{k} \space 1,\overbrace{0,0,..,0,0}^{k} \space 1,$ etc
With $k = 1$ we have the formula $\dfrac{1}{2}\times \sin(x\times \pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2})+\dfrac{1}{2}$
With $k = 2$ we have  $1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1$ etc one explicit formula is the following;
$$\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{2}{3}\times \cos(\dfrac{2}{3} \times x \times\pi)$$
But I can't manage to find a formula for the general case.
Is there such a formula ? If there is what is it ? Can it be done using only sines and cosines ?

Hint for one approach: for any finite set $S$ and $x \notin S$, there is a polynomial $f$ such that $f(y) = 0$ for $y \in S$ and $f(x) = 1$. Think about a formula of the form $f(\cos \frac{2 \pi x}{k + 1})$.

@StefanLaton offers a solution. I would suggest a frame change. If your wish is to communicate with your reader, a complex contrived formula is much worse than the description in words you propose in your question. It would even be better in code than an impenetrable formula.

Apparent inconsistency in the posted question.  The pattern for general values of $~k~$ contains no 1 on the LHS of the sequence, while the pattern for $~k = 2~$ does contain a 1 on the LHS of the sequence.

Since your pattern is $(k+1)$-periodic, you can use the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT). This gives you a general method regardless of the periodic pattern.
For any periodic pattern $x_0, x_1, \dots, x_k$ of period $(k+1)$, the DFT is defined, for $q=0, 1\dots$, as
$$X_q=\sum_{p=0}^k x_p e^{-2i\pi\frac{pq}{k+1}}$$
In your case, since $x_0=0, x_1=0, \dots, x_k=0, x_{k+1}=1$, this reduces to $X_q=e^{-2i\pi\frac{qk}{k+1}}$.
To recover the original sequence, you can apply the inverse-DFT:
$$x_p=\frac 1 {k+1}\sum_{q=0}^k X_q e^{2i\pi \frac{pq}{k+1}}$$
In your case, this reduces to $$x_p=\frac 1{k+1}\sum_{q=0}^k e^{2i\pi \frac{(p-k)q}{k+1}}$$
And since you know you started with a sequence of real numbers, you can just take the real part if you don't want to deal with complex exponentials:
$$x_p=\frac 1{k+1}\sum_{q=0}^k \cos\left(\frac{2\pi(p-k)q}{k+1}\right)$$
Edit: If you're comfortable using a formula that sometimes looks like it's giving $\frac 0 0$ then you can derive from the formulas above that
$$x_p=\frac{1}{k+1} \frac {\sin\left( {\pi (p-k)}\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi (p-k)}{k+1} \right)}$$
where you for the case $p=k$ you need to take the limit $p\rightarrow k$
